# Core Data arraycontroller binding: valueForUndefinedKey

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

all

I have a NSTableView as well as a three NSTextFields displayed inside a NSWindow. (in the IB).
  The entity is designed like this

```
Entity: Data
Attributes:
    Title      String
    URL        String
    UserName   String
    Password   String
```

I have successfully bound the NSArrayController to the managedObjectContext, and NSTableView to the arrayController's Title attribute, and the NSTableView can show all the titles correctly.

I want to implement the following task:

```
When user click one of the row in the NSTableView, the rest of the three NSTextFields can show the records of that row, respectively URL< username and password.
```

so I do the following for the URL part

bind a NSTextField to NSArrayController's selection.URL

**When i run the program, it gives errors, however, if I uncheck the "Raises for not applicable keys" in the binding property, the program can be successfully launched, and value can be correctly shown in the text field. can anyone explain why?**

the error says:

```
 [<NSTableView 0x102240d60> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key URL.
```

Here's the part of error log:

```
2012-01-17 11:52:57.533 Quills[98683:407] An uncaught exception was raised 2012-01-17 11:52:57.534 Quills[98683:407] [<NSTableView 0x102240d60> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key URL. 2012-01-17 11:52:57.540 Quills[98683:407] (   0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8abd2286 __exceptionPreprocess + 198  1   libobjc.A.dylib    0x00007fff8d84cd5e objc_exception_throw + 43     2   CoreFoundation       0x00007fff8ac5c4c9 -[NSException raise] + 9    3   Foundation            0x00007fff8d1e8783 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:]
+ 240   4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d11f462 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 108  5   Foundation                          0x00007fff8d11f3e9 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 392     6 Foundation                          0x00007fff8d13ee76
-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 348    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff85ab33f1 -[NSArrayController
_multipleValueForKeyPath:atIndex:] + 84     8   AppKit                              0x00007fff85ab24e5 -[NSArrayController _singleValueForKeyPath:] + 151   9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8581909a
-[_NSControllerObjectProxy valueForKeyPath:] + 77   10  Foundation                          0x00007fff8d13ee39 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 287     11  AppKit                              0x00007fff85818f46
-[NSBinder _valueForKeyPath:ofObject:mode:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:] + 654    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff85818c30 -[NSBinder valueForBinding:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 171  13  AppKit                              0x00007fff85a1cc92 -[NSValueBinder
_referenceBindingValue] + 31    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff85a1caa3 -[NSValueBinder
_adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:]
+ 647   15  AppKit                              0x00007fff85a1c788 -[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 303     16  AppKit                              0x00007fff85a345af
-[NSTextValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 43     17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8580abdb
-[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 591
```

Comment: make sure you have bound the "URL" key to the arraycontroller

Comment: hi, Shanti, Why? My array controller binds the managedObjectContext and the NSTableView binds the arrangedObject.title from the arrayController, and the URL textfield is supposed to display the URL corresponding to the selected title of from the NSTableView. So when I choose a title in the NSTableView, the "selection" shall refers to this data, thus, selection.URL shall points to the URL attribute, am I making sense? (if not, what property shall I bind this URL to the array controller? - content ?)

Comment: @Sheldon you're making perfect sense. I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: First of all, don't call your Core Data entity "Data" or "String" or whatever. If you do want to use data, prefix it with something like "Sheldon_Data". Core Data relies to a great extent on string parsing and it can easily get confused. Secondly, attributes should be lower-case, so title, url, user_name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same issue, except with a NSOutlineView and a NSTreeController.

My issue ended up being that I had connected my NSTreeController's content outlet to my NSOutlineView. As soon as I removed this, references to selection started working.

I suspect you may have done something similar given your error says NSTableView is lacking the key rather than NSManagedObject.